# Special linear Lie algebra.

Tags: lie-algebras

When I am reading the Notes on Lie algebra by Hans Samelson, there is a sentence:

> The standard skew-symmetric (exterior) form $det[X, Y ] = x_1y_2−x_2y_1$
>   on $\mathbb{C}^2$ is invariant under $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$ (precisely because of the vanishing of the trace).

Here, $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the Special linear Lie algebra.

Can someone explain it?

Does it mean that for any $M \in sl(2,\mathbb{C})$, we have $det[MX, MY ] = det[X, Y ]$? But when $M=0$, it fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Lie algebras, "invariant" means "sends to 0." So the claim is something like det[Mx,My]=0.

Comment: This comes from the fact that Lie algebras are infinitesimal versions of Lie groups. When you differentiate g(t).x=x with respect to t, the right hand side goes to zero!

Comment: I haven't learnt any Lie groups yet... Anyway thank you for your help!